# Mavericks 10.9 trouble installing gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, osx-mavericks

I've been struggling to install jekyll on my mac, don't know much about ruby or configuring/debugging these messages.

I'm getting the following when running "sudo gem install jekyll"

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
make: *** No rule to make target `/include/universal-darwin13/ruby/config.h', needed by `porter.o'.  Stop.


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/ext/gem_make.out
```

"gcc --version" returns the following:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: What is the output of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/ext/gem_make.out ?

Comment: Have you upgraded xcode?

Comment: I've updated xcode its version 5.0, output is the same message just logged in the file.

Comment: Try running `xcode-select --install` in your terminal.

Comment: This error will even happen after dev tools are installed. The 'make "DESTDIR="' error only happens for certain types of gems including mysql or mysql2. Think its a ruby 2.0 config.h issue?

Answer (score 2):

use this command :

```
$ sudo xcode-select -r
```

then

```
$ sudo gem install jekyll
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Besides upgrading xcode, as rayrashmi suggested, you have to actually *open* it so the command-line tools are properly installed.

(I am assuming you installed the command-line tools from xcode before upgrading to mavericks, if you haven't they're under `Preferences → Downloads → Components`, [official info here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/).)

Then, just upgrade gem if you haven't already done so and install jekyll and any other library you were using, like pigments.

As they say, "worked for me."